# What other HTML tags other than the form tag be used to send data back to the server?

Tags: html, forms, rest

I know that we can use the `<form action="location" method=POST(or GET)>` tag to send data back to the server by giving it a action and method attribute. My question is, what other HTML tags let you do the same(let you send user input back to the server)? and can we specify the `method="GET or POST"` and action attribute in other tags or can they only be used with the  tag.

Comment: Are you interested only in HTML, or considering Javascript as well?

Comment: My question involves both HTML and JS. Does Javascript provide any mechanism for that functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<form>` element is the de-facto element to send data to a web server (via the attributes that you mentioned as well as all of the other child input-related elements within the form).

Outside of the pure-HTML space, the options expand quite a bit in terms of the flexibility for how your client can interact with the server (e.g. leveraging AJAX, the Fetch API, etc.) by reading forms, arbitrary elements, and more.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, So it is safe to say that <form> element is the only way for us to send data back to the server? plus you can add child elements within the <form> tag if you want to use a specific tag for something?

Comment: In a pure HTML world, yes. Any input-related elements (e.g. `<input>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>`, etc.) will all bind the `name` attribute on each of those elements with the respective value and post those to the server. 

As mentioned, the use of other technologies such as AJAX expand on this and leverage Javascript to allow more flexibility to the requests (i.e. what they include, content types, etc.).

Comment: Any request that hits the server will 'send data' back to the server. A `<form>` element is the only one that can send a POST request, but `<a href="...?size=large&color=blue">` will send a GET request with those two key/value pairs to the server. Without Javascript, the user isn't generally in control of that data - they haven't entered it, but it's a request all the same.